# ftplib capture and process ftp server response code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use ftplib to transfer files, then capture response code from server.

This is Filezilla output, which is what I want to capture after "URL:",

Response:   226 transfer complete. URL: https://domain.com/d7178d98-ahfh12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP('ftp.debian.org')
>>> login_response = f.login()
```

now `login_response` contains : `'230 Login successful.'`
this works with other ftplib methods :

```
>>> tr_response = ftp.retrbinary('RETR README', open('README', 'wb').write)
```

will result in : `'226 Transfer complete.'`